# How to configure jest in Angular app with import of OwlMomentDateTimeModule in library?

Tags: javascript, angular, jestjs, babel-jest, ts-jest

There is a library on Angular with the following module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularTestLibComponent } from './angular-test-lib.component';

import { DateTimeAdapter, OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, OwlDateTimeIntl, OwlDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { OwlMomentDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime/date-time/adapter/moment-adapter/moment-date-time.module';
import { MomentDateTimeAdapter, OWL_MOMENT_DATE_TIME_ADAPTER_OPTIONS } from 'ng-pick-datetime/date-time/adapter/moment-adapter/moment-date-time-adapter.class';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AngularTestLibComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    OwlMomentDateTimeModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    AngularTestLibComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: OwlDateTimeIntl },
    { provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, useValue: 'ru' },
    { provide: DateTimeAdapter, useClass: MomentDateTimeAdapter, deps: [OWL_DATE_TIME_LOCALE, OWL_MOMENT_DATE_TIME_ADAPTER_OPTIONS] },
    { provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: null },
  ],
})
export class AngularTestLibModule { }
```

And when I import this library to the Angular application and running tests (in the application), I get an error:

```
home/ivan/projects/angular-test-2/my-test-app/node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/date-time/adapter/moment-adapter/moment-date-time.module.js:7

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I think this is happens because import with absolute path: `ng-pick-datetime/date-time/adapter/moment-adapter/moment-date-time.module`. But dunno how solve this problem. How to fix this?

Application files

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        '<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'
    ],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
        // "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/file.js",
    }
};
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-test-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "jest --coverage --config ./jest.config.js",
    "test:watch": "jest -o --watch --config ./jest.config.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.1",
    "@dzencot/my-test-angular-lib": "0.0.10",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "@testing-library/angular": "^10.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^8.4.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.5",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.2"
  }
}
```

repos:

app - https://github.com/dzencot/angular-testing-app

lib - https://github.com/dzencot/angular-testing-library